# Is it safe to load a .so file in NDK

Tags: android-ndk

Can the host application enumerate the imports a .so makes?

If all imports are deemed safe per white list, is it safe to load it into a android process?
The idea is to allow .so plugins to be loaded to render VR content.

How can NDK get the imports list on runtime?

Comment: What does "imports" mean for you? Is it a complete list of required external symbols and libraries or something else?

Comment: correct. all static external symbols.

one thing i just realized, can the plugin .so just call android syscall to load another .so without the load function being in the imports list